Проблема с запуском сервера Lando



делаю lando start и получаю крах
еще бывает, что файл .lando.yml, в котором настройки запуска сервера, просто блокируется для удаления и изминения
Пробовал менять путь в File sharing в докере, но возможно я ставил не то, что надо.
Пытался давайть доступ к файлам, к которым закрывался доступ при lando start и один раз что-то запустилось, но криво
max@maxim:~/Desktop/php/Projects/kinopoisk-lite$ lando start
Let's get this party started! Starting app kinopoisk-lite...
[+] Running 5/5
 ✔ proxy Pulled                                                                                 8.1s 
   ✔ b731cd68f421 Download complete                                                             1.3s 
   ✔ cbdbe7a5bc2a Download complete                                                             1.3s 
   ✔ f16506d32a25 Download complete                                                             1.9s 
   ✔ 2d2982f034f0 Download complete                                                             4.9s 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Started                              1.7s 
[+] Running 16/16
 ✔ appserver Pulled                                                                            45.6s 
   ✔ 220476acde96 Download complete                                                             0.3s 
   ✔ 4f4fb700ef54 Download complete                                                             0.8s 
   ✔ 5297ee4610ef Download complete                                                             0.8s 
   ✔ 50bafef51e69 Download complete                                                            12.5s 
   ✔ ef2c8d255e6b Download complete                                                             0.7s 
   ✔ 5debfed13712 Download complete                                                             0.8s 
   ✔ 6e7be8164eee Download complete                                                            31.6s 
   ✔ 245093625352 Download complete                                                             0.8s 
   ✔ 6533c3eba3f3 Download complete                                                            25.1s 
   ✔ c9294594c534 Download complete                                                            19.2s 
   ✔ eabfae0cc40f Download complete                                                            22.4s 
   ✔ 26f4bb2bdc9f Download complete                                                             0.7s 
   ✔ 46da5340d408 Download complete                                                             0.9s 
   ✔ 41d1b374a83a Download complete                                                             0.4s 
   ✔ e37fd0cec2da Download complete                                                            38.0s 
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network kinopoisklite_default        Created                                                 0.1s 
 ✔ Container kinopoisklite_appserver_1  Started                                                 1.9s 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container kinopoisklite_appserver_1  Running                                                 0.0s 
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 2.2.22) successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

[+] Stopping 1/1
 ✔ Container kinopoisklite_appserver_1  Stopped                                                10.3s 
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/kinopoisk-lite.build.lock'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/kinopoisk-lite.v4.build.lock'

██╗   ██╗██╗  ██╗     ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗██╗
██║   ██║██║  ██║    ██╔═══██╗██║  ██║██║
██║   ██║███████║    ██║   ██║███████║██║
██║   ██║██╔══██║    ██║   ██║██╔══██║╚═╝
╚██████╔╝██║  ██║    ╚██████╔╝██║  ██║██╗
 ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝     ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝
                                         

An unrecoverable error occurred while starting up your app!
Here are a few things you can try to get back into a good state:

 ◼ Try running Run lando rebuild
 ◼ Try restarting in debug mode Run lando restart --debug
 ◼ Try checking the logs with Run lando logs

If those fail then consult the troubleshooting materials:

 ◼ https://docs.lando.dev/help/logs.html
 ◼ https://docs.lando.dev/help/updating.html

Or post your issue to Slack or GitHub

 ◼ Slack - https://launchpass.com/devwithlando
 ◼ GitHub - https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/new/choose

 
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/kinopoisk-lite.v4.build.lock'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/logs/kinopoisk-lite-error.log'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/logs/lando-error.log'
max@maxim:~/Desktop/php/Projects/kinopoisk-lite$ lando start
Let's get this party started! Starting app kinopoisk-lite...
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/max/.ssh'

██╗   ██╗██╗  ██╗     ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗██╗
██║   ██║██║  ██║    ██╔═══██╗██║  ██║██║
██║   ██║███████║    ██║   ██║███████║██║
██║   ██║██╔══██║    ██║   ██║██╔══██║╚═╝
╚██████╔╝██║  ██║    ╚██████╔╝██║  ██║██╗
 ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝     ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝
                                         

An unrecoverable error occurred while starting up your app!
Here are a few things you can try to get back into a good state:

 ◼ Try running Run lando rebuild
 ◼ Try restarting in debug mode Run lando restart --debug
 ◼ Try checking the logs with Run lando logs

If those fail then consult the troubleshooting materials:

 ◼ https://docs.lando.dev/help/logs.html
 ◼ https://docs.lando.dev/help/updating.html

Or post your issue to Slack or GitHub

 ◼ Slack - https://launchpass.com/devwithlando
 ◼ GitHub - https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/new/choose

 
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/max/.ssh'
max@maxim:~/Desktop/php/Projects/kinopoisk-lite$ lando start
Let's get this party started! Starting app kinopoisk-lite...
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1  Started                             11.4s 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container kinopoisklite_appserver_1  Started                                                 1.2s 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container kinopoisklite_appserver_1  Running                                                 0.0s 
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 2.2.22) successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

[+] Stopping 1/1
 ✔ Container kinopoisklite_appserver_1  Stopped                                                10.3s 
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/kinopoisk-lite.build.lock'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/kinopoisk-lite.v4.build.lock'

██╗   ██╗██╗  ██╗     ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗██╗
██║   ██║██║  ██║    ██╔═══██╗██║  ██║██║
██║   ██║███████║    ██║   ██║███████║██║
██║   ██║██╔══██║    ██║   ██║██╔══██║╚═╝
╚██████╔╝██║  ██║    ╚██████╔╝██║  ██║██╗
 ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝     ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝
                                         

An unrecoverable error occurred while starting up your app!
Here are a few things you can try to get back into a good state:

 ◼ Try running Run lando rebuild
 ◼ Try restarting in debug mode Run lando restart --debug
 ◼ Try checking the logs with Run lando logs

If those fail then consult the troubleshooting materials:

 ◼ https://docs.lando.dev/help/logs.html
 ◼ https://docs.lando.dev/help/updating.html

Or post your issue to Slack or GitHub

 ◼ Slack - https://launchpass.com/devwithlando
 ◼ GitHub - https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/new/choose

 
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/kinopoisk-lite.v4.build.lock'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/logs/kinopoisk-lite-error.log'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/logs/lando-error.log'

lando version 3.21.2
Docker version 4.34.2
В File sharing указан один путь /home/

приложите полный вывод ошибок при lando start и укажите, какую версию Lando и Docker используете, также какие именно изменения были сделаны в конфигурации Docker (в File Sharing) и Lando перед запуском //код ошибки НЕ картинкой, а в тег обратный оберните пожалуйста

@Dev18 внес правки, посмотрите пожалуйста

Ошибки явно связаны с правами доступа EACCES: permission denied - Уточните, проверяли ли вы права на директорию /home/max/.lando

@Dev18 я пытался давать доступ с пощью sudo chown -R user:groups  но это без толку, вылазит снова ошибка с доступом

Если проект был скопирован с другого источника chown может не сработать (Права на директории не были полностью изменены рекурсивно для всех вложенных файлов) ...

Проект был перенесен из телеграм, но я еще только что попытался запустить сервер в новой папке и все равно получаю это
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/cache/my-lando-app.v4.build.lock'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/logs/my-lando-app-error.log'
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/max/.lando/logs/lando-error.log'
